# Express inserts "www" in front of domain on SOME routes but not other

Tags: javascript, express, dns

I have the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'super secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.get('/session', (req, res) => {
  res.contentType('json').json(req.session);
});
app.get('/health-check', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));

app.listen(8080, () => console.info(`Listening on port 8080!`));
```

When i go to `<domain>/health-check` the browser opens `<domain>/health-check` (no surprise there). However when i go to `<domain>/session` the browser is redirected to `www.<domain>/session`. Why is this? Why are express redirecting some routes to `www.<domain>` but not others?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I *think* this might be a DNS thing. Have you checked the settings on your registrar's site?

Comment: @ChristianScott what should i look for? I've bought the domain through namecheap, and i haven't changed any of the default settings (expect pointing it to my ip, ofc).

Comment: Ah, if you haven't changed anything then I doubt it's DNS. Are you using a web server like NGINX or apache?

Comment: @ChristianScott The server is a standard ubuntu server installation, so its using the default settings on an NGINX web server. (or it should be, i might have messed it up when i told it to redirect trafic on port80 to the express app. Its my first time having to deal with NGINX)

Comment: You've not changed anything in the nginx conf? I'm out of ideas 

Comment: @Olian04 Have you excluded the browser as source of this problem? As in, have you tried opening the session URL in another browser? I'm asking because I've experienced the browser "fixing" certain URLs like `fritz.box` and the like.

Comment: @ChrisG Now i feel stupid. Turns out its not happening in either firefox nor edge. That's a problem though... since the fact that chrome changes the url it also messes with the session token... so i get 2 sessions from the same browser&user...

Comment: @Olian04 Right, this shouldn't happen on other people's Chrome though. Afaik this only happens if you happen to have entries in your browser history that trigger this.

Comment: @ChrisG Like what? What kind of browser history entries would trigger this?

Comment: A similar thing happened to me recently - safari refused to let me visit `http://localhost:3000` & always upgraded to `https://localhost:3000` because I'd been using https with a previous project

Comment: @Olian04 Not sure, but I'm willing to bet that a fresh Chrome installation will not randomly add `www` to your URLs. The aforementioned history pages are from previous visits to your domain I assume. Which means your users will not generate those and thus the problem won't occur for them.

Comment: @ChrisG Correct. I just installed a fresh chrome canary and its not injecting `www`. Super odd behavior.